# Find the index of minimum value of tuple pairs in Python

Tags: python, arrays, lambda, tuples, min

With a list of tuple pairs `n=[(266, 116), (81, 296), (148, 115), (324, 303)]` I am trying to efficiently find the index of the left-most points. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
min_index = 0
for i in range(1,len(n)): 
     if points[i][0] < points[min_index][0]: 
            minIndex = i
```

but to me this does not look efficient. I also found a solution using lambda function, which might at least look more appealing (idk about the time complexity here of the min function)

```
min(n, key = lambda t: t[0])
```

but this gives me the actual coordinates, not the index which I want. How can I change the lambda function to give me the actual index, and is there any better solution in terms of *time complexity*? Thank you

Comment: There is nothing wrong or "inefficient" in your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `range(len(n))` in the `min` instead of `n`:

```
>>> min(range(len(n)), key = lambda i: n[i][0])
1
```

Note: the loop approach is not in anyway inefficient since there is no apparent pattern in the data, so you can't, for instance, use a dichotomy approach (such as binary search), and the `min` does *almost* the same thing, it's just preferred sometimes because it is built-in, more concise, and less prone to errors.

Comment: thanks a lot! From what I understand, although theoretically, this has the same complexity as a normal loop, in reality, because at the C layer, the min/max built-in functions avoid bytecode interpreter, it can be a little bit faster, so there is no way of finding the minimal value in a better complexity than O(n), right?

Comment: @SamuelV. Exactly, since you have to loop through all elements, it's better to do it the built-in way than your way, if you can (you can think of exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You could also `enumerate` in the `lambda` part to get both the index and the value as:

```
n = [(266, 116), (81, 296), (148, 115), (324, 303)]
min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(n), key = lambda n: n[1][0])
print(min_index, min_value)   # 1 (81, 296)
```